# CMake is not able to run simple test

Tags: c++, cmake

Running on Ninja Generator and am currently failing to run a test code in CMake with this output:

Any thoughts?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
The C compiler

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/jamieza/source/repos/CMakeProject2/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_59a30 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_59a30.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_59a30.exe
FAILED: cmTC_59a30.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_59a30.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_59a30.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_59a30.exe /implib:cmTC_59a30.lib /pdb:cmTC_59a30.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_59a30.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_59a30.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
The system cannot find the file specified
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.        C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake  66

Comment: Try to run CMake from a Visual Studio 2019 native tools command prompt so that the environment variables for compiling are setup correctly.

Comment: I think `--mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND` is the problem

Comment: Is it possible to mix Ninja and cl.exe? That doesn't sound like a thing.

Comment: @sweenish - it is absolutely possible. I do it all the time (from a native command prompt).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and since there is no answer posted, I would share the solution that worked for me. The build output from the console does not give many clues. I had to look under CMakeFiles for CMakeError.log. In my case, it could not open and link 'kernel32.lib' but that information was not present in the VS build output window.

```
/out:CMakeCCompilerId.ex/out:CMakeCCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCCompilerId.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'    

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
```

This post on [cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19815) helped me. I had to modify VS2019 install and add the C++/CLI component. Everything went smoothly after.